# Getting the length of an NSTextField's text property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstextfield

I am having a problem finding the length of a text field's `text`!

I searched here a lot and just found that it would work with `textfield.text.length` or something like that.
My problem is `textfield.text` is not working for me!
If I write this code: `textfield.text;` then I get an error like this:

> property "text" not found on object of type `NSTextField`

I have to find the length of an text field in order to limit the number of characters.

What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of the classes in AppKit, as opposed to UIKit, don't have properties. [`NSTextField`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextField_Class/Reference/Reference.html) doesn't even have a method called `text`. You need the [`stringValue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000073-BAJEBFBE) method, which is inherited from [`NSControl`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSControl)

Answer (score 2):

The generally accepted way of doing this (limiting the length of NSTextField) is by using the NSFormatter helper class.  [See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827014/how-to-limit-nstextfield-text-length-and-keep-it-always-upper-case)

Answer (score 0):

To limit the length you add the delegate methods to your controller by adding

```
< UITextFieldDelegate >
```

in the header file. Then in the implementation add the following method:

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

In here just check the length and either return the string or just the string length you want.
You can get the length with:

```
[[textfield stringValue] length]
```

In interface builder be sure and add the file owner as the delegate to the text field