# Custom NSFormatter for Textfield in XCode 4

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsformatter

I'm trying to use a class I have which overrides NSFormatter in an OS X app.  I tried an example from a book but it's from an older version of XCode.  My problem is I don't know how to set my NSTextfield's formatter.  I'm not sure if something changed now that Xcoded has the IB built in or I'm doing something else wrong.  It looks like you used to be able to control click your text field and it would bring up a menu.  In the outlets section of the menu it says I'm suppose to see a "formatter" selection.  That is not listed in my outlets section of the menu.

I don't think it makes a difference, but my NSTextfield is in a NSScrollview.  I'm still very new to Cocoa (coming from a C# and C++ background).

Comment: What are You trying to limit with NSFormatter in Your NSTextField?

Comment: I'm just trying to limit the number of characters that can be entered in the nstextfield

Answer (score 1):

You can simply subclass *NSNumberFormatter* like this:

in **.h**

```
@interface NumberFormatterSubclass : NSNumberFormatter {

}

@end
```

in **.m**

```
@implementation NumberFormatterSubclass


- (BOOL)isPartialStringValid:(NSString **)partialString
   proposedSelectedRange:(NSRangePointer)proposedSelRange
          originalString:(NSString *)origString
   originalSelectedRange:(NSRange)origSelRange
        errorDescription:(NSString **)error 
{

    if ([*partialString length] > 4) { 
        return NO;
    }


    return YES;
}
```

Don't forget to add *NSNumberFormatter* on Your *NSTextField* and change *NSNumberFormatter* class to Your created subclass in *identity inspector*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the text field is not limited to numbers.  I found this solution to creating a formatter class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827014/how-to-limit-nstextfield-text-length-and-keep-it-always-upper-case.   I just can't find how to link the nstextfield to any formatter

Comment: It's not limiting numbers.. It's limiting letters and and numbers. It's limiting to 4 symbols letters or numbers. And You can link formatter by dragging it on NSTextField and then change formatter class to Your created subclass in identity inspector how I was said in my post earlear. Furthermore if You don't like how it sounds "NSNumberFormatter" use "NSFormatter" same my writed code will work!

Comment: When subclassing an NSFormatter you must also implement the methods: stringForObjectValue: and getObjectValue:forString:errorDescription:  See "Creating a Custom Formatter" https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/CreatingACustomFormatter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000196