# Set max length for mutiple NStextfield in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa-touch, nstextfield

I create multiple NSTextField in XIB, now I want to set max lengh for each NSTextField. How can I do that by best way?

Comment: You can find answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827014/how-to-limit-nstextfield-text-length-and-keep-it-always-upper-case

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/827014/how-to-limit-nstextfield-text-length-and-keep-it-always-upper-case

Comment: I added 2 file CustomTextFieldFormatter but i don't know how to use it . Can you show me? thanks much @Andrey