# How do I programatically move the cursor from one NSTextField to another after a character count has been reached?

Tags: swift, macos, user-interface, cocoa

I'm trying to create a window where the user can enter the activation key for the product and I've done so by creating 5 different NSTextField's, as shown in the image.

[image: Activation Code Field]

What I want to add to this is `the ability for the cursor to move to the next text field once a character count has been reached (which is 5 characters maximum per textfield)`.

I did find code for this but it was for IOS and didn't work since i didn't know what changes to make [(Code for the IOS version)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35331839/how-to-move-cursor-from-one-text-field-to-another-automatically-in-swift-ios-pro)

here's the code I tried

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ActKeyOne.textDidChange(Notification.Name.init(rawValue: "textchanged"))
}
```

it gave the error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Notification.Name' (aka 'NSNotification.Name') to expected argument type 'Notification'
```

Comment: Use the text field notification to count the number of characters in each text field.

Comment: [`textDidChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/1428954-textdidchangenotification) & [`makeFirstResponder(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419366-makefirstresponder). Try it and if it wont work for you, edit your question with code that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Instead of `textDidChangeNotification` you can use a delegate and [controlTextDidChange(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontroltexteditingdelegate/3005177-controltextdidchange).

Comment: Looks like controlTextDidChange( :) worked better thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to part of this this question was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50825393/12959607) by @cheesey

here is the complete code to create a window that takes the license key for a product from a user `(This is using swift 4)`.

First set the Text Fields as the delegates and first responders in the `viewDidLoad` Function and then change the first responder once the string limit is hit

```
class CommercialActivationView: NSViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    @IBOutlet weak var firsttextfield: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondtextfield: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var thirdtextfield: NSTextField!

    firsttextfield.window?.makeFirstResponder(firsttextfield)
    firsttextfield.delegate = self
  }

  func makeFirstResponder() {
    
    if firsttextfield.stringValue.count == 5 {
        firsttextfield.window?.makeFirstResponder(secondtextfield)
    }
    if secondtextfield.stringValue.count == 5 {
        secondtextfield.window?.makeFirstResponder(thirdtextfield)
    }
  }
}
```

Now to create the extension that creates the character limit or the text field every time the user edits the `TextField` `(Here i'm limiting the number of characters per text field to 5)`.

```
extension CommercialActivationView: NSTextFieldDelegate {
func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
    
    let object = obj.object as! NSTextField
    if object.stringValue.count > 5{
        object.stringValue = String(object.stringValue.dropLast())
        makeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

This works such that once 5 characters are reached in 1 `TextField` it switches to the next one automatically. Also the code I've posted is for 3 `TextFields` more text fields can be add if needed.